# How to make User Interface of add contact detail same like in iPhone Contact List?

Tags: ios4, uitableview, contact-list

I am making an app, in which I am making custom contact list for this application, now I made add button to add contact in my custom contact list.

Now I want to add all the detail (name, mobile, email, photo etc..) of contact, same like iPhone new contact detail has, and with same userInterface that apple use in add contact...

I think its custom group table view but still I can not get how they use it, and I want to do like exactly same...